# Send post data and cookiefile in Google App Engine PHP runtime

Tags: php, google-app-engine, post, cookies, curl

I have a code written in PHP and currently running on my shared hosting. Now I'm going to move it on Google App Engine.

`sendRequest()` method sends post data and cookies to another website and returns a response.

```
private function sendRequest($url, array $data = array()) {
    $ch = curl_init(self::URL_BASE);
    $curlConfig = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_COOKIE => "user_name=" . $this->username . "; user_password=" . md5($this->password));
    if ($url == self::URL_LOGIN) {
        $this->cookieFile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
        $curlConfig[CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR] = $this->cookieFile;
    } else {
        $curlConfig[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = $this->cookieFile;
    }
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

**Problems:**

- CURL module is not supported in App Engine
- `tempnam()` function is disabled

I've searched a lot, but couldn't find any alternatives. `fsockopen()` is also disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the stream context to set the cookies on the request, per the example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php).

Not sure from your code why you want to persist the cookies and for how long - can you use [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) for this purpose instead?